# why when i reload page, i get a empty string in localstorage, and when page reloaded i get a empty string tag in tagListContainer

Tags: javascript, local-storage

i think every thing is good. This is the first time I have such a problem
i save tags array in local and when page reload i get information from local storage but when page reload i get a empty string in localstorage and i get that in my list tag. i dont know where empty string add to array and how remove that

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const removeAllBtn = document.querySelector('.removeAll')
const tagListContainer = document.querySelector('.tagListContainer')
let counterText = document.querySelector('.details p span')

let tags = [];

let currentNumber = 10


//***********counter number ************/
function count () {
    input.focus()
    counterText.textContent = currentNumber -  tags.length
}


//***********Remove all tags ************/
removeAllBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    tags = []
    removePreviousTag()
    count()
    setDataToLocal()
})


//***********Remove tags by clicking ************/
function removeTag (tagElem, tagValue) {
    tagElem.parentElement.remove()
    
    let findIndexTag = tags.indexOf(tag => tag === tagValue)

    tags.splice(findIndexTag, 1)

    count()
    setDataToLocal()
}


//***********Remove tags before adding ************/
function removePreviousTag () {
    setDataToLocal()
    tagListContainer.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(tag => tag.remove())
}

//***********Generate tag ************/
function generateTag () {
    let tagTitle = input.value.toLowerCase().trim()

    //push tow string with , in array
    tagTitle.split(',').forEach(tag => {
        tags.push(tag);
    });

    [...tags].reverse().forEach(tag => {
        const html = `<li>${tag} <i class="uit uit-multiply" onclick="removeTag(this, '${tag}')"></i></li>`
        tagListContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html)
    })
    
    count()
    setDataToLocal()

    input.value = ''
};



input.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' && tags.length < 10 && input.value !== '' && !tags.includes(input.value.toLowerCase())) {
        removePreviousTag()
        generateTag()
    }
})


//***********Set data in local storage ************/
function setDataToLocal () {
        localStorage.setItem('tags', JSON.stringify(tags))
}

//***********get data from local storage ************/
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let getData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tags'))
    if (getData?.length) {
        tags = getData
        removePreviousTag()
        generateTag()
    }
})
```

**html code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tags Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Unicons CDN Link for Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/thinline.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="title">
        <img src="tag.svg" alt="icon">
        <h2>Tags</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Press enter or add a comma after each tag</p>
        <ul class="tagListContainer">
          <!-- Add Tags Here -->
          <input type="text" spellcheck="false" />
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <p><span>10</span> tags are remaining</p>
        <button class="removeAll">Remove All</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

**css code**

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #5372f0;
}

::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background: #5372f0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 496px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 18px 25px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

.wrapper :where(.title, li, li i, .details) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.title img {
  max-width: 21px;
}

.title h2 {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.wrapper .content {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.content ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 12px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #a6a6a6;
}

.content ul li {
  color: #333;
  margin: 4px 3px;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px 8px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e3e1e1;
}

.content ul li i {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  color: #808080;
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #dfdfdf;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content ul input {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper .details {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.details button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #5372f0;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
}

.details button:hover {
  background: #2c52ed;
}
```

Comment: If you can please remove the line break between `c` and `onst` on line 2? thanks

Comment: You could consider sprinkling the code with some `console.log();` things, perhaps `debugger;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are reloading the page then you are calling `generateTag` function and at that time `tagTitle` is empty string. Hence it is adding an empty string in the tags list.

You can add a simple check that if the tagTitle is NOT an empty string then only add that tag otherwise don't add it in tags list.

```
//***********Generate tag ************/
function generateTag() {
  let tagTitle = input.value.toLowerCase().trim();

// ✅ Check if tagTitle is NOT an empty string 
  if (tagTitle !== '') {
    tagTitle.split(',').forEach((tag) => {
      tags.push(tag);
    });
  }

  [...tags].reverse().forEach((tag) => {
    const html = `<li>${tag} <i class="uit uit-multiply" onclick="removeTag(this, '${tag}')"></i></li>`;
    tagListContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
  });

  count();
  setDataToLocal();

  input.value = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

generateTag function is called from load

> window.addEventListener('load', () => {

in script.js
you could just add in generateTag function, something like:

```
function generateTag () {
    let tagTitle = input.value.toLowerCase().trim()
    if (tagTitle?.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
```